# How to exclude login url from rails admin and devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I have a system written in RoR and Devise, and I use rails admin as my admin system.

The problem is that, since I used devise as authentication service, and login url is /admins/sign_in, however, all urls start with /admin is managed by rails admin and need to be logged in, so this is a dead loop.

What I want to do is to use /admin/sign_in as login url and /admin/sign_out as logout url.

Any idea how to exclude these urls from rails admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem in two ways:

1. Set root of `rails_admin` to something other than `admin`, may be `system_admin`, this will avoid any URL collisions. Eg:

   ```
   mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/system_admin', as: 'rails_admin'
   ```
2. Put `devise_for :users` first, like:

   ```
   devise_for :users
   mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
   ```

Comment: I prefer option 2, :D
Thank you for help!

Comment: If you are going for option 2 I recommend adding specs so that in future no one can accidentally break it.